# Kubernetes beginner: trigger simple actions between apps

Tags: kubernetes

Very simple question, I have a front-end app running in kubernetes. I would like to create a back-end containerized app that would also be in kubernetes obviously.

User actions in the frontend would need to trigger the execution of a command on the backend (`echo success!` for example). The UI also needs to know what was the command's output.

What is the best way to implement this in k8s?
Either through an internal service, or the two apps can also be in the same pods.

Perhaps there is some kind of messaging involved with applications such as rabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your application how you are planning.

Some people host frontend on bucket and from there send HTTP request to backend or so.

You can keep frontend and backend in different PODs or in a single POD also.

For example, if you are using the Node JS with express, you can run as simple API service POD also and keep frontend with it also to serve.

You can use the K8s service name for internal communication instead of adding the Message broker(RabbitMQ, Redis also can be used) unless your web app really needs it.

I would also recommend checking out the :  https://learnk8s.io/deploying-nodejs-kubernetes

Github repo of application : https://github.com/learnk8s/knote-js/tree/master/01

Official example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/

Comment: yeah I guess that the easiest would be to include my backend app into an API, and then to just send requests from the frontend to `http:myservice:80 `? Or am I wrong

Comment: yes correct you are right, as default in nature by K8s service it will do load balancing behind running pods so you dont have to worry about anything else just send POST to backend service and you are all set

Comment: You definitely should not keep the front-end and back-end in a single pod. A pod, like a container, should have a single main container and do a single job. The ability to run multiple containers in a pod is so that we can have sidecars (like proxies) deployed with our services.